# HTML email mobile responsive

Tags: html, css, html-email

I've created and HTML email, and it all works just fine, but there are some parts where I'm using inline css (padding: 0 36px 15px 140px) to have an empty part before the text. It all looks good on desktop, but when I open it on a mobile device, the long lines appears in two lines, because the 140px padding on the left side is too big for them. How can I solve this?

This is what I've tried so far:

```
<style type="text/css">


    @media screen and (max-width: 525px) {


    .smaller {
        padding: 0px 36px 15px 100px;
    }
```

```
<td style="padding: 0px 36px 15px 140px; font-size: 16; font-family: Helvetica; font-weight: bold;" class="smaller">
```

So I'm declaring a media query for smaller devices, then I try to apply this to the class, but the padding doesn't change. How can I do this? The style is in the head, shall I put it somewhere else?

Comment: Yes. Nothing should be in the head when doing email. Put it all inline.

Comment: What email clients does your email code not work in? Does it work in _any_ client?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `!important`, that overwrite your `inline-style`

```
@media screen and (max-width: 525px) {

    .smaller {
        padding: 0px 36px 15px 100px !important;
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Override the inheritance with the !important directive.

https://www.w3.org/wiki/Inheritance_and_cascade

```
.smaller {
    padding: 0px 36px 15px 100px !important;
}
```

EDIT: I see I was slow on the draw...  ok, are you sure you are closing your style tag?   (Sometimes it's the obvious stuff... happens to me all the time.)

Comment: @Micheal Allison yes, I do close it. !important doesn't seem to work

Comment: Are you calling this new style after the other styles?  Like after your main CSS file?  Maybe it's being overridden.

Comment: everything is inline in my html file, as you can see in the example above. So I think I do, by putting class="smaller" in the end

Comment: I have two bits of advice.

1. Use the box-sizing property: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/box-sizing/

2.  Use the ::after selector:  https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/a/after-and-before/